# На локальной машине в ИЕ6 не работает javascript, при этом все нормально работает на сервере.

Tags: jquery, javascript, internet-explorer

Здравствуйте, сегодня столкнулся с очередным глюком. При работе с локальной версией сайта в ие6 перестал работать яваскрипт (такое впечатление, что он просто отключается для загружаемой страницы), при этом, та же версия сайта, но подгруженная с сервера - прекрасно работает в том же ие6. Не могу понять, что может мешать на локалхосте отработке клиентских ява скриптов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще IE использует разные политики безопасности для internet и localhost. Смотрите настройки для локальной сети

Comment: Да проверял я настройки,стоит самый низкий уровень защиты для всего.

Comment: Хотя Павел, Вы были правы. Я просто выставлял низкий уровень для локальной интрасети в Tools - Internet Options - Security, что не довало нужного эффекта, а нужно было открыть детальную информацию и поставить галочку для  выполнения скриптов и все заработало. Видно дефолтные настройки даже на самом низком уровне безопасности не включают скрипты по умолчанию. Большое спасибо.

Comment: Недавно наткнулся, что в  IE11 для интранет по-умолчанию тоже отключена большая часть встроенных функций javascript, из-за чего AJAX не работает.